# sorting not working in p:datatable

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I am using primeface datatable but its sorting not working, can anyone help me!! I have tried to add #{v.elementID} in sortBy but it still not workin

```
<p:dataTable value="#{dashboardBean.topTenMenuItem}"
                                        var="v" paginator="true"
                                        rows="#{msg['dashboard.product.mapping.datatable.rows']}">
                                        <p:column sortBy="#{v.elementId}" headerText="ID">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{v.elementId}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column sortBy="#{v.name}" headerText="Name">
                                            <h:link value="#{v.name}" />
                                        </p:column>

                                        <p:column sortBy="#{v.updateBy}" headerText="Update By">
                                        <h:outputText value="#{v.updateBy}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column sortBy="#{v.statusName}" headerText="Status">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{v.statusName}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                        <p:column sortBy="#{v.updateDate}" headerText="Updated On">
                                            <h:outputText value="#{v.updateDate}" />
                                        </p:column>
                                    </p:dataTable>
```

and bean is

```
public List<RecentItemDashDTO> getTopTenMenuItem() {
    Map<String, Object> sessMap = CommonUtil.getSessionMap();
    SessionDTO sessionDTO = (SessionDTO) sessMap.get(WebConstants.SESSION_DTO);
    countryCode = sessionDTO.getLoggedinCountryCode();
    String languageCode = sessionDTO.getDefaultLanguageCode();
    topTenMenuItem = dashboardService.getTopTenRecentMenuDashData(countryCode,languageCode);
    return topTenMenuItem;
}

public void setTopTenMenuItem(List<RecentItemDashDTO> topTenMenuItem) {
    this.topTenMenuItem = topTenMenuItem;
}
```

Comment: You need to specify the value to sort by in your attribute. That value is an EL expression `#{v.updateBy}`.

Comment: I have done changes as per XtrmeBiker but its still not sorting,

Comment: Please check that your datatable is inside <h:form> tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got another solution for sorting.

```
private String initList;
public String getInitList() {
            myTopTenMenuItem=getTopTenMenuItem();
            return null;
}
```

and in xhtml

```
<h:form name="form" prependId="false">
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{dashboardBean.initList}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My own experience says that to use this feature you'll need a `List` object in your BackingBean, with getters and setters. Not a reference. Try that with any init method and let us know if it worked.

```
public class DashboardBean {

private List<RecentItemDashDTO> myList;

public List<RecentItemDashDTO> getMyList()
{
    return myList;
}

public void setMyList(List<RecentItemDashDTO> myList)
{
    this.myList = myList;
}

public List<RecentItemDashDTO> getTopTenMenuItem()
{
    Map<String, Object> sessMap = CommonUtil.getSessionMap();
    SessionDTO sessionDTO = (SessionDTO)sessMap.get(WebConstants.SESSION_DTO);
    countryCode = sessionDTO.getLoggedinCountryCode();
    String languageCode = sessionDTO.getDefaultLanguageCode();
    topTenMenuItem = dashboardService.getTopTenRecentMenuDashData(countryCode, languageCode);
    return topTenMenuItem;
}

@PostConstruct
public void init()
{
    myList = getTopTenMenuItem();
}

}
```

XHTML:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{dashboardBean.myList}" ... >
```

Comment: getting exception in console as  Error listenerStart while adding init method.if i remove init and add list to setMyList, then list become null;

Comment: What kind of exception? Can you post a stacktrace fragment?

Comment: it started working when I removed @PostConstruct and called setter as setMyList(topTenMenuItem); inside the getTopTen getter.